# MergeSort with Linked List - Split function C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, mergesort

I'm having issues with my split function in my MergeSort class. It works for the first few, but then I get a segmentation fault. I think it's my for loop and choosing the correct middle node, but I can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated, here is my code:

Header:

```
#ifndef MERGE_LIST
#define MERGE_LIST

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class mergeList {
    public:
        struct node {
            int data;
            struct node* next;
        };

        mergeList();
        void push( struct node** head_ref, int new_data );
        void printList( struct node * nptr );
        //void merge( struct node** headRef );
        struct node* SortedMerge( struct node* a, struct node* b );
        void merge(struct node** headRef);

    private:
        int size;
        //void merge( struct node** headRef, int s );
        //void split( struct node* headRef, struct node** a, struct node** b, int mid );
        void split(struct node* source, struct node** frontRef, struct node** backRef, int s);
        void merge(struct node** headRef, int s);
};

#endif
```

Source:

```
#include "mergeList.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

mergeList::mergeList( ) {
    size = 0;
}

void mergeList::push( struct node** head_ref, int new_data ) {

    struct node* new_node = ( struct node* ) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->data  = new_data;
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);    
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
    size++;
}

void mergeList::printList( struct node * nptr ) {

    while( nptr ) {
        cout << nptr->data << " ";
        nptr=nptr->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void mergeList::merge(struct node** headRef) {
    merge( headRef, size);
}

void mergeList::merge(struct node** headRef, int s)
{

    if( s < 2 )
        return;

    struct node* a;
    struct node* b;
    struct node* head = *headRef;

    bool addOne = false;
    int mid = s/2;

    if( s % 2 != 0 )
        addOne = true;  

    cout << "B4 SPLIT!" << endl;
    cout << "AddOne: "  << addOne << endl;
    cout << "s: " << s << endl;

    split(head, &a, &b, s);

    merge(&a, mid);

    //if( addOne )
    //  mid++;

    merge(&b, mid);

    *headRef = SortedMerge(a, b);
}

//Use a pointer to split the list
void mergeList::split(struct node* headRef, struct node** _a, struct node** _b, int s) {

    struct node* a;
    //struct node* b;
    if ( s < 2) {
        *_a = headRef;
        *_b = NULL;
    }
    else {
        a = headRef;

    if( s != 2 ) {
        for( int i = 0; i < s/2; i++ )
            a = a->next;
    }
            *_a = headRef;
            *_b = a->next;
        a->next = NULL;
    }
}

struct mergeList::node* mergeList::SortedMerge( struct node* a, struct node* b ) {

    struct node* result = NULL; 

    if ( a == NULL )
        return b;
    else if ( b == NULL )
        return a;
    if( a->data <= b->data ) {
        result = a;
        result->next = SortedMerge( a->next, b );
    }
    else {
        result = b;
        result->next = SortedMerge( a, b->next );
    }

    return( result );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you run in a debugger such as gdb or  dbx to see where it is segfaulting?

Comment: I don't really know how to use it, but I know its some where in or after the for loop

Comment: @David Then you should consider this a good opportunity to learn to use debugging tools. If you continue programming you will have to learn at some point.

Comment: Same feelings as kappamaki.  They're very easy to use to do simple stuff like catch a segfault or figuring out where an infinite loop is.  Google "gdb cheat sheet" to get started.  You'll need to compile with the -g flag to tell the compiler to leave debugging info in.  This will tell you exactly the line your problem is on and save you hours over pouring through source or even adding debugging statements.

Using debugger = good kind of lazy, putting off learning = bad kind of lazy.

Comment: I'm still not really familiar, but I got the cheat sheet and got my way through and found the error. Thanks.